# 51% attack + ignore blocks not mined by yourself

Tags: blockchain, majority-attack

If you own 51% of the mining power and decide to ignore all blocks not mined by yourself.
You would eventually end up having the longest chain, and would eat up the 49% of block-reward you werent getting prior. 
And now control 100% of the blocks, and could censor transactions etc, since any blocks not mined by you would eventually be a stale fork.

Is there some measure that would stop this?
It seems if you control 51%, it would be in your economical interest to ignore blocks not mined by yourself. 
(other than it being bad publicity for btc, and maybe crash the price)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The owner of 51% can get 100%. This is attack-51 itself.

> Is there some measure that would stop this?

no